# SQL Server database blocking issue with @@SERVERNAME

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

We have a locking issue on one of our database servers. After investigating in detail what is causing the blocking, we found out that this is one of our functions. What was really surprising is that the function does *nothing* - just returns formatted server name.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetReleaseName]()
RETURNS NVARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN   
    DECLARE @serverName NVARCHAR(20)
    DECLARE @ReleaseVersion NVARCHAR(20)

    SET @ReleaseVersion = '20170807'
    RETURN @@SERVERNAME + '_UAT_' + @ReleaseVersion
END
```

How can it be that `@@SERVERNAME` is causing any blocking?

Comment: Can you share how you determined that this caused blocking

Comment: What do you mean under the "blocking"? If you mean your code executing slower than without your function, the answer is DO NOT USE SCALAR FUNCTIONS (they are executed row per row with the overhead you pay on every function call)

Comment: With dmv:
select * from sys.dm_exec_requests WHERE blocking_session_id <> 0

Answer (score 1):

Scalar functions have poor performance.

Try replacing your function with an inline table valued function.

Here's an example:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetReleaseName_ITVF]()
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN(
    SELECT @@SERVERNAME + '_UAT_20170807' as FullServerName
)
```

Usage:

```
SELECT * FROM [table] CROSS APPLY GetReleaseName_ITVF()
```